Why do we take the real part of the trace in the definition of the Wilson loop (lattice)?
I am getting confused on the definition of the (expectation value of) Wilson loop. Do we take only the real part of the trace in the definition (on the lattice)?
$W_C=Tr\prod_{l\in C} U_l$
or
$W_C=ReTr\prod_{l\in C} U_l $
Which one is the correct definition? If it is the first one, then why is it that
$\langle W_{C}\rangle \sim e^{-an_tV(r)}$
And we don't have an imaginary part ?
